# I want to add web3 package to react project - BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: reactjs, web3-react

I add web3 package to my react project and start.

```
yarn add web3

yarn start
```

But it causes following errors:

```
...
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed these issues for 4 days. Then I found the reason of this problem.

I changed to lower version of mainly 2 of packages - `react-router-dom` and `react-scripts`.

```
ex: 
react-scripts - 5.0.0 : error causes
react-scripts - 4.0.3 : success
```